# Issues with 3 door Monte. Trying to call a variable from another method

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to figure out how to get a 3 card monte type game done for school. I'm currently drawing all 3 doors and (I think) I have the right code to check for the mouse position in each door. My problem is changing the color of each door depending on the right/wrong answer. So if they click the door on the right and that's correct, I want it to turn green. I'm getting:

```
Attribute error: 'rectangles object has no attribute 'rightRect' on line 48
```

I'm new to Classes, but I was told that's the best way to get this job done. Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
#3DoorMonte

from graphics import *

win = GraphWin('Shapes', 450, 400)
center = Point(500,500)


rPoint1 = Point(312, 89)
rPoint2 = Point(396, 306)
mPoint1 = Point(178, 90)
mPoint2 = Point(270, 306)
lPoint1 = Point(53, 90)
lPoint2 = Point(140, 306)

class Rectangles:
    def rightRectangle(self):
        rightRect = Rectangle(rPoint1, rPoint2)
        rightRect.setFill('blue')
        rightRect.draw(win)
        rightLabel = Text(Point(355,110),"Door 3")
        rightLabel.draw(win)

    def midRectangle(self):
        midRect = Rectangle (mPoint1, mPoint2)
        midRect.setFill('blue')
        midRect.draw(win)
        midLabel = Text(Point(221, 110),"Door 2")
        midLabel.draw(win)

    def leftRectangle(self):
        leftRect = Rectangle(lPoint1, lPoint2)
        leftRect.setFill('blue')
        leftRect.draw(win)
        leftLabel = Text(Point(96, 110),"Door 1")
        leftLabel.draw(win)

    def checkSelection(self):
        selection = win.getMouse()
        print (selection)
        if (selection.getX() > rPoint1.getX()
            and selection.getX() < rPoint2.getX()
            and selection.getY() > rPoint1.getY()
            and selection.getY() < rPoint2.getY()):
            R.rightRect.setFill('red')
            R.rightRect.draw(win)

        if (getMouse.getx() > mPoint1.getx()
            and getMouse.getx() < mPoint2.getx()
            and getMouse.gety() > mPoint1.gety()
            and getMouse.gety() < mPoint2.gety()):
            midRect.setFill('red')

        if (getMouse.getx() > lPoint1.getx()
            and getMouse.getx() < lPoint2.getx()
            and getMouse.gety() > lPoint1.gety()
            and getMouse.gety() < lPoint2.gety()):
            leftRect.setFill('red')

R = Rectangles()


def main():
    R.rightRectangle()
    R.midRectangle()
    R.leftRectangle()
    R.checkSelection()
    win.getMouse()
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your class members such as `rightRect`, you have to prepend `self`. For example `self.rightRect`.

```
def rightRectangle(self):
    self.rightRect = Rectangle(rPoint1, rPoint2)
    self.rightRect.setFill('blue')
    self.rightRect.draw(win)
    self.rightLabel = Text(Point(355,110),"Door 3")
    self.rightLabel.draw(win)
```

Answer to question #2:

The issue is with these 2 lines:

```
        R.rightRect.setFill('red')
        R.rightRect.draw(win)
```

`R` is not defined inside of your `class Rectangles`.

Also with:

```
midRect.setFill('red')
leftRect.setFill('red')
```

So instead you can do:

```
        self.rightRect.setFill('red')
        self.rightRect.draw(win)
        self.midRect.setFill('red')
        self.leftRect.setFill('red')
```

Comment: thanks! Do you mean to add it to the first instance like within the def rightRectangle(): or where I'm calling it in def checkSelection(): ?

Comment: I have improved my example. Only the definition.

Comment: fantastic, thank you. I get a new error though:
     name 'rightRect is not defined in checkSelection():rightRect.setfill('red)

it looks to me like it's defined though...am I not understanding this right?

Comment: ohhhhhmygod. That works! Thank you very much. If I have other questions about other parts of the assignment, do I update this thread or do I start a new thread because it's a new issue?

Comment: It's better to start a new thread. Also don't forget to mark the answer so other users don't have to look at this question anymore.